# PDE: Advection equation with time-dependent BC

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have the following simple advection equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t}= - \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} , \quad0<x<1, \quad t>0  
\end{equation}

We also  have the following initial and boundary conditions: 
\begin{equation}
p(x,0)=0\\
p(x,t)= f(t) \quad at \quad x=0 \\
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x}=0 \quad at \quad x=1
\end{equation}

The PDE should satisfy TWO boundary conditions(BCs). It seems that we can get rid of the inhomogeneous BC by defining $q(x,t)=p(x,t)+f(t)$. Which method could I use to get an explicit solution for this PDE?

Comment: The Laplace transform method will give you a solution based on just the Initial and the first boundary condition. Here, the problem is the second boundary condition at $x=1$ and how to satisfy it.